# How to fix emojis showing gibberish on incoming SMS messages Google Fi service

Tags: sms, emoticons

Yesterday for no apparent reasons I started to see text like this in the body of the text if the sender had both text and emojis:

```
hi you smell like poo!
~9weuaisigjei3
```

When I expected to see:

```
hi you smell like poo!
```

Now if they send only emojis I would see this:

```
~06WjjgASrCDcGQg
```

In any case it's annoying.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I got on chat with [Google FI Support](https://support.google.com/fi/) who walked me through through these fixes.

1. Goto Settings>Apps>GoogleFi>Storage and tap Clear Data
2. Open Google FI app and complete setup.
3. If this recurs make sure to contact support to make sure your network is fixed.